# conda fails when installing protobuf for tensorflow

Tags: python, anaconda, protocol-buffers, conda

I am using anaconda command prompt to install protobuf

```
conda install -c anaconda protobuf
```

It fails with this error

> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
> Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

My system is WIN 10. I'm using protobuf for tensorflow-gpu 1.8

My python version is 3.6.0. My anaconda version is 4.8.3 and my configuration is

```
add_anaconda_token: True 
add_pip_as_python_dependency: True 
aggressive_update_packages: - ca-certificates - certifi - openssl allow_conda_downgrades: False 
allow_cycles: True 
allow_non_channel_urls: False 
allow_softlinks: False 
always_copy: False 
always_softlink: False 
always_yes: None 
anaconda_upload: None 
auto_activate_base: True 
auto_stack: 0 
auto_update_conda: True 
bld_path: changeps1: True 
channel_alias: conda.anaconda.org
```

Comment: Are you having problems with protobuf after installing tensorflow-gpu, or with tensorflow-gpu? I am able to run the command conda install -c anaconda protobuf, but i get the same error you see when installing tensorflow-gpu. `conda install tensorflow-gpu=1.8` For debugging, what version of conda are you running? `conda --version`, also what is your conda configuration? `conda config --show`

Comment: Also, can you use version tensorflow-gpu=1.9 instead? It doesn't have the package compatiblity issues

Comment: my conda version is 4.8.3 @DonaldStierman

Comment: add_anaconda_token: True
add_pip_as_python_dependency: True
aggressive_update_packages:
  - ca-certificates
  - certifi
  - openssl
allow_conda_downgrades: False
allow_cycles: True
allow_non_channel_urls: False
allow_softlinks: False
always_copy: False
always_softlink: False
always_yes: None
anaconda_upload: None
auto_activate_base: True
auto_stack: 0
auto_update_conda: True
bld_path:
changeps1: True
channel_alias: https://conda.anaconda.org

Comment: What are the contents of the environment? Have you tried creating a new environment will all the packages you need?

Comment: @mONA can you check my answer below and see if it works and meets your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the tensorflow-gpu and protobuf packages from conda-forge instead.

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow-gpu=1.8
```

protobuf is included in this install so no need to install separately.

Update:

It looks like the package on anaconda is not functional at all. Even creating a new conda env with only the tensorflow-gpu=1.8 package (see below) will generate a conflict error. The version on conda-forge is fine.

not working (anaconda):

```
  conda create --dry-run --json -c anaconda -n dummy tensorflow-gpu=1.8

  {
      "error": "UnsatisfiableError: ",
      "exception_name": "UnsatisfiableError",
      "exception_type": "<class 'conda.exceptions.UnsatisfiableError'>",
  }
```

working (conda-forge):

```
  conda create --dry-run --json -c conda-forge -n dummy tensorflow-gpu=1.8

  {
      ...
      "success": true
      ...
  }
```

Comment: THANKS for reply , what worked for me is waiting for 6-7 hours conda install -c anaconda protobuf it kept solving suddenly 600+mb file downloaded